# Why can I only organize columns in some lists

Tags: list, list-view, column

I have several lists in SharePoint that allow me to organize the columns in the list settings. But other lists do not have that option and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is different between the lists that determines whether that option is or is not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a normal behavior that occurs in a case of you are allow the management of content types on this list. by setting `Allow management of content types?` to `Yes` in the `list Setting` >  `advanced setting`

[image]

So you can't find `Column ordering` option as shown below

[image]

Otherwise, You can find `Column ordering` when `Allow management of content types?` set to `No`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I also have found that if I select a content type (example would be "Item") under Content Types and that brings me to a page specific to that content type where I can choose the order of columns. That allows me to leave Content Type Management enabled

Comment: You are welcome bro, yes you are right, you can manage the columns order of content type itself and apply it for all ist that inherit this type or not?